# Filter expression 'FirstName ' does not evaluate to a Boolean term

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I am binding a DropDownList, I have FirstName in the 1st column and LastName as a DDL in the second column

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
    DataColumn productIDColumn = new DataColumn("FirstName");
    DataColumn productNameColumn = new DataColumn("LastName");

    myTable.Columns.Add(productNameColumn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ds = get();
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var categoryID = (e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
        var expression = "FirstName "+categoryID;

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

        DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select(expression);
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            DataRow newRow = myTable.NewRow();
            newRow["UserId"] = row["UserId"];
            newRow["LastName"] = row["LastName"];
            myTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        ddl.DataSource = myTable;
        ddl.DataTextField = "LastName";
        ddl.DataValueField = "UserId";
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am getting an error like `Filter expression 'FirstName ' does not evaluate to a Boolean term` at DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select(expression);

Can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Does 'DDL' mean a Drop Down List in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression doesn't make any sense.  I would expect something along the lines of:

```
var expression = "FirstName = 'John'";
```

or

```
var expression = "CategoryId = 42";
```

Check out the docs for the Select method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

Comment: oops i miss that but even though i do like that the DDL is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare 2 values in your expression. Read this article: [C# DataTable Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

Comment: Even though i compare the values, DDL is empty.

Comment: are you sure your expression is right? you're comparing the FirstName to the ID (or that's what it looks like): var expression = "FirstName = " + categoryID;

Comment: The thing is even the categoryid also empty dont know why??

Comment: Add the CategoryID key to the DataKeyNames of your GridView1. Then, in your GridView1_RowDataBound1 event get the ID: 
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                int myDataKey = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["categoryID"]);
            }

Comment: But when populating the DDL the datatable is empty.

Comment: is guess your expression doesn't match any rows. put a breakpoint on DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1"); and see that is the value of categoryID an see if it's what you expect

Comment: well that's your problem. you're not getting the category ID the right way. read more about the gridview here http://asp-net-example.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/aspnet-gridview-rowdatabound-event.html